# Visual C++ corrupt unicode strings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, unicode, compiler-construction

I've been trying to find any info but google totally failed me. The following code just cannot compile to standard unicode, and I get corrupt stuff in MessageBoxW(it's MessageBoxW, i've disassembled and tested exe in ollydbg), however my username, "юзер" from path to exe displays correctly in message (as expected). Problem is C compiler, for some reason fails to compile my strings correctly. I tried both L and TEXT() with same result.

This is the only source file on input, encoded as UTF-8 without BOM (notepad++).

```
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE

#include <windows.h>

void main() {
    wchar_t exe[254];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL,(wchar_t *)&exe,254);
    MessageBox(NULL,(wchar_t *)&exe,L"юзер",0);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Build commands (I tried building in Visual Studio 2003 and Visual C++ 6 but gave up long ago, switching to manual compiling in cmd.exe to get raw result):

```
cl.exe /c /nologo test-unicode-ui.c
link.exe /nologo /nodefaultlib /entry:main kernel32.lib user32.lib /OUT:test-unicode-ui.exe test-unicode-ui.obj
```

It's absolutely no use, every method I tried gives me corrupt static strings from source code, but it's okay with internal processing (like, stuff you get from winapi is trusted and works fine). I can, of course, compose few strings by hand, in runtime, luckily I don't have many, but doesn't that sound strange?

What is it obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: I would suggest you stop using compilers over ten years old.  Newer versions of Visual Studio compile and run that code fine.

Comment: You should really clarify your question. First you say the code "cannot compile". Then you tell us that when running (so it seems to compile) it gives the wrong output. Also you should strip your code to the relevant part - the string literal - and get rid of the misleading exe/GetModuleFileName (and not only tell us the details in comments to answers).

Comment: @James: I'm sorry, but how exactly did compilers work with unicode in the past? I'm downloading newer version now but that's weird.

Comment: @James it seems like working in vs2008... i'll try to learn from it's compiler command line, because it won't compile it correctly again if using in cmd like before. but it didn't work at all in vs2003. i mean, at all. thanks.

Comment: They didn't work with Unicode.  They usually just interpreted source files as plain old ASCII.

Comment: @James i see, they just won't work. how did programmers write unicode strings then, in the past?

Comment: I would say it's fairly rare even today to include Unicode text directly in a source file. On larger projects, you're much more likely to pull displayed text in from some sort of external source such as a resource file or database. Also don't forget that Unicode really has only had widespread adoption within the last ten years or so - a fact you can easily see from the level of support for Unicode in your older compilers. Before Unicode, programmers dealt with the myriad of different code pages as best they could - or, more often, ignored anything outside the basic ASCII character set.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of VC++ automatically detect the "UTF-8 without signature" encoding of source code.

In older versions of VC++ you can try to add UTF-8 signature (aka "BOM"), or use the [`setlocale` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e22ty2t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

the short answer: double-check the encoding and use visual c 2008 compiler(might even work from 2005). utf-8 != microsoft unicode, which is utf-16le. if you encode input file with utf-16le, you get correct strings when building from cmd.exe with cl from vc2008.

Comment: source code encoding has nothing to do with encoding of compiled `wchar_t` strings.

Comment: did you just try it yourself?

Comment: I didn't said it doesn't work. It works not because MS uses UTF-16LE but because parser can detect encoding. In VC++2008 UTF-8 works as well as UTF-16.